# OpenSSL и Win64

Tags: c, winapi, сокет, openssl, x86-64

Смотрю одну библиотеку и вижу код

```
  bio = BIO_new(amqp_openssl_bio());
  if (!bio) {
    status = AMQP_STATUS_NO_MEMORY;
    goto error_out2;
  }

  BIO_set_fd(bio, self->sockfd, BIO_NOCLOSE);
```

Интересует последняя строчка. `self->sockfd` это хендл сокета и на Win64 имеет размер 64 бит.

Смотрю в `bio.h` из OpenSSL. `BIO_set_fd` это макрос

```c
# define BIO_set_fd(b,fd,c)      BIO_int_ctrl(b,BIO_C_SET_FD,c,fd)
```

А функция `BIO_int_ctrl` последним параметром принимает `int`

```
long BIO_int_ctrl(BIO *bp, int cmd, long larg, int iarg);
```

Я чего-то не понимаю, или получается, что OpenSSL под Win64 не работает?

Вот нашел такой [багрепорт](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/8169)

> In windows the descriptor for socket is SOCKET rather than int.
>   When building in x64, SOCKET is 64 bits. I see that the following methods assume that a socket is int:
>
> ```
> BIO_new_socket
> BIO_connect
> BIO_listen
> BIO_accept_ex
> BIO_closesocket
> BIO_sock_error
> BIO_sock_info
> ```
>
> Is it possible to add support for x64 windows sockets?

И ответ разработчика

> Even though sizeof(SOCKET) is 8, it's safe to cast it to int, because
>   the value constitutes an index in per-process table of limited size
>   and not a real pointer. And we also depend on fact that all processors
>   Windows run on happen to be two's-complement, which allows to
>   interchange INVALID_SOCKET and -1.

Ну и гуглится подобный [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953639/is-it-safe-to-cast-socket-to-int-under-win64) на enSo. Там со ссылкой на Руссиновича вообще утверждают, что хватит 24 бит.

Но в том же MSDN [сказано](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/winsock/socket-data-type-2?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

> Socket handles may take any value in the range 0 to INVALID_SOCKET–1.

Comment: так в чём вопрос? вроде как по ссылкам уже всё обсудили...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Т.е. использовать знаковый int и надеяться, что Microsoft ничего не поменяет?

Comment: в общем да... не то что было бы сложно увеличить размер переменной дескриптора, но пока я в общем солидарен с мейнтейнером openssl'я, что это несколько излишне...